# Fastest way to get the last element of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

What is the fastest way to get the last element of a list in Haskell. Also in next iteration, I want to remove first and last element of the list. What is the most elegant way to do it? I am trying list comprehension, but that does not look very efficient!

Comment: I think retrieving the *last* element efficiently is difficult. Maybe you should explain the context in more detail, so one can see if there might be other data structures that fit your needs better.

Comment: there is little reason to doubt that Prelude.last has a good implementation. The better question, as phimuemue says, is whether, if you are using `last` a lot you don't need something other than lists, e.g. Data.Sequence or something of that kind.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`last` and `init` will do the job just fine for a one-off. However they are both *O(n)*, so if you need to manipulate both ends of a list often, as you seem to imply, you might want to consider using [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Sequence.html) instead, which supports *O(1)* insertion and removal of items at both ends.

Answer (score 127):

You can use [the `last` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.0.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:last) to get the last element of a list.

As for how to remove the first and last elements, you could use `(init . tail)`, but I don't know how efficient that is.

I think this image from [Learn You A Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/) shows the list functions fairly well:

[image: illustration of list functions]

Comment: Isn't `(init . tail)` wrong/missleading? It should be `(head . tail)`.

Comment: @nulvinge (head . tail) would just return the second element in the list. See the picture above :)

Comment: Ops, sorry, you're right. Been doing to much scheme lately to recognize . as composition...

Answer (score 8):

I'll post the Prelude implementation since it hasn't been posted yet:

```
listLast :: [a] -> a
listLast [x] = x --base case is when there's just one element remaining
listLast (_:xs) = listLast xs --if there's anything in the head, continue until there's one element left
listLast [] = error "Can't do last of an empty list!"
```

Note that I changed the function name to `listLast` so that it can be run without conflicting with normal Prelude.  You could, of course, do `import Prelude hiding(last)`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove first and last:

```
take (len(l)-2) (drop 1 l)
```

or maybe

```
init (drop 1 l)
```

This also results in almost optimal code.

Answer (score 1):

This answer focuses on dealing with weird conditions (like empty lists) in a maximally flexible way, and on building up bigger functions from smaller ones using some library functions. It's *not* the best answer for someone first learning about lists, but rather a couple steps past that.

For the following, you will need

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))
```

and you will need to either use GHC 7.10 and import `Data.List (uncons)` or define

```
uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
uncons [] = Nothing
uncons (x:xs) = Just (x,xs)
```

You can write a safe form of `init` like this:

```
init' :: [x] -> Maybe [x]
init' = foldr go Nothing
  where
    go x mxs = Just (maybe [] (x:) mxs)
```

A version of `tail` can be written

```
tail' :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
tail' = fmap snd . uncons
```

So then you can get a maybefied

```
trim' :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
trim' = init' >=> tail'
```

The `>=>` is a sort of backwards monadic composition. `init' >=> tail'` is a function that applies `init'` to its argument to get a `Maybe [a]`. If it gets `Nothing`, it returns that. If it gets `Just xs`, it applies `tail'` to `xs` and returns that.

From this, you can easily make a trimmer that trims lists with 0, 1, or 2 elements down to empty lists:

```
trim :: [a] -> [a]
trim = maybe [] id . trim'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
last' :: [a] -> a
last' ys = foldl1 (\_ -> \x -> x) ys
```

It is O(n), just like the built in library function list.

Answer (score -2):

```
(head.reverse) [1..100]
```

Is an alternative to `last` to get the last element.

```
drop 1 (take (length [1..100] - 1) [1..100])
```

removes the first and last list element. The source for `drop` and `take` look like it might be faster than `(init . tail)`.

```
(reverse.drop 1) ((reverse.drop 1) [1..100])
```

is another variant. But I guess slower because of the double reversal.

Comment: `length` is rarely something you want to do without a good reason. There is no good reason here. The same goes for `reverse`.

Comment: @dfeuer -- I've recently started haskell, so forgive my ignorance. Why should `length` rarely be used? I do this in my code: `rotate' n xs = drop (length xs - n) xs ++ take (length xs - n) xs` which uses `length` twice. Is this bad practice? If so, why?

Comment: @xilpex, there are several problems. It's an `O(n)` operation to start with. It makes an extra pass over the list. And in the context of a lazy garbage-collected language, it can often lead to much more memory retention and garbage collection times than alternatives. I don't know if there's a more efficient way to implement your rotation function; it might be inherently inefficient.