# find last element of a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I wrote the following code to find the last element of a list in haskell:

```
myLast (x:xs) = do
    ret <- if xs == [] then x else (myLast xs)
    return ret
```

The idea is to traverse the list until we are at an element which has the empty list as its next element. When we find it we set `ret` to that element.
It makes sense for me but when I run the code inside the interactive shell I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num (m0 b0)) arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

**edit 1**

The reason I used `do` was because I saw that pattern being used somewhere  to also traverse a list, so I thought I could do the same here. I'am avoiding libraries for now to get comfortable with the language.
I wrote the function avoiding the do keyword and now it works:

```
myLast(x:xs) = if xs == [] then x else (myLast xs)
```

There's now just an issue with the empty list case. How to approach this in haskell?

Comment: Why are you using `do` notation? What Monad do you think you are using?

Comment: Please do not use `do` notation, unless you are convinced that you need *monads* (you do not need these here), and furthermore the same applis for `return`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to get the last element of a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376937/fastest-way-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-haskell)

Comment: `==` is a library function (actually, a class method). Although there's no reason to avoid library functions in general, you actually want to avoid `==` here because using it the way you do imposes an `Eq` constraint on the elements of the list. You could replace `xs == []` with `null xs` to solve the problem, but it seems a bit nicer to just do more pattern matching.

Comment: Importing `Data.Monoid (Last (..))` and `Data.Maybe (fromJust)`, we can write `last = fromJust . getLast . foldMap (Last . Just)`. As everyone knows, `fromJust` is a terrible idea, so we should instead write `last = getLast . foldMap (Last . Just)`. That gives us a somewhat different (but better!) type for `last`.

Comment: I think you should check what actually `return` does. It is _not_ that return you know from other languages. In Haskell you should understand it as "return to the monad", so `return :: a -> [a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
myLast (x:xs) =
```

to be equal to

```
                if xs == [] then x else (myLast xs)
```

Great, `xs == []`, so let's just put it back in:

```
myLast (x:[]) =                  x
```

but what about the `else` part? Well, let's add another equation for that,

```
myLast (_:xs) =                          myLast xs
```

and we're golden.

What if we call it with an empty list `[]` though? No definition case will *match*, and we will get some kind of a run-time error. Well, same thing happens with the built-in function `last` too, so we're no better and *no worse* than Haskell itself here.

What is that *match* that I mentioned, you ask? That's how Haskell functions get invoked. Each function definition can have several clauses, starting with the function's  name, and containing a *pattern* for each expected argument.

In a left hand side of an equation,

- `(x:[])` is a pattern, matching any singleton list. It can also be written `[x]`. `x` will  refer to the list's only element, if used in the right-hand side of the equation.
- `[]` is a pattern, matching any empty list.
- `(x:xs)` is a pattern, matching any non-empty list.  `x` will  refer to the list's *head* (i.e. first) element, if used in the right-hand side of the equation; and `xs` will refer to the *rest* of the elements in a list (which are also, a list -- also known as its *tail*).

But wait, you ask. Wouldn't *both* clauses *match* for a singleton list, the first for the pattern `[x]` and the second for `(_:xs)` with `xs` matched up with an *empty list*, `[]`?

Why yes, they both *would* match indeed; `(x:[])` and `(_:xs)` are *not* mutually exclusive.

But that's OK, because in Haskell, if the first clause has matched, that's it -- *that* is the clause that gets executed, and no other attempts at any additional pattern matching and clause selection are made.

That would be Prolog, and that's quite another language.

Answer (score 2):

let's start with the signature of your function

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
```

now, for an empty list input, what can be expected as the output?  How you can make up an instance of an arbitrary type `a`?

Alternatively, you can defer the handling of missing last element to the callers of your function.

```
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
```